# html2fpdf using php jquery and ajax - Export with full CSS

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, html2pdf

I am using html2fpdf to export html as a pdf file.

However it is not exporting it as it looks on he page, i.e. without the css.

How can I get it to export the html as it is formatted on the page...?

Comment: I use tcpdf (www.tcpdf.org). It generates pdf with full css. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is your css on the page or is it in an external css file?

Comment: its in an external file....which i'm guessing is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the export with the content of a featured example.
If it displays correctly, it means that the problem is that your html is not valid.

Another well documented library here : http://html2pdf.fr/en/

And Documentation : http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil

PS: you finally found the way to force download of your file? If so, please come back and accept the answer we provided you.

Comment: No, neither of the answers helped me. Sorry.